# how to convert string to decimal expression?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, console-application

I am trying to convert string to perform arithmetic expression but getting format expression. I want the expression to be calculated and final answer.

```
// original value
     string text = @"4'-8"x5/16"x20'-8 13/16";

                string path = text.Replace("'", "*12").Replace("-", "+").Replace("x", "+").Replace(" ", "+").Replace(@"""", "");
                System.Console.WriteLine("The original string: '{0}'", text);
                System.Console.WriteLine("The final string: '{0}'", path);

                    Console.WriteLine();

                    decimal d = decimal.Parse(path, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

// after converting got this value in debug
//'4*12+8+5/16+20*12+8+13/16'
```

Comment: What's the precise exception and on which line do you get it

Comment: Using `decimal.Parse` is not going to evaluate a mathematical expression stored in a string.  It doesn't work that way.  You're going to have to extract the operands and do the math in your code.

Comment: decimal d = decimal.Parse(path, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: why are you converting the "x5/16" to + 5/16"?

Comment: x should be converted to + and then added to the final value.

Comment: Is this a homework problem to parse feet and inches with fractional inches values and add them?  Is your result to be in feet and inches or decimal feet?

Comment: Also, the argument to `File.ReadAllText` needs to be the path to a file; you are providing the mathematical expression instead.

Comment: @PaulGibson : yes, to decimal feet.

Comment: @rory.ap i removed path and kept an example value from that. no problem with that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `DataTable` class to evaluate a mathematical expression string, using the `Compute()` method, passing a `String.Empty` as the second parameter.

```
var parsingEngine = new DataTable(); //in System.Data
int i = (int)parsingEngine.Compute("3 + 4", String.Empty);
decimal d = (decimal)parsingEngine.Compute("3.45 * 76.9/3", String.Empty);
```

Just be aware that `Compute` returns an object, and you must be careful to cast it to an appropriate type based on what your mathematical expression should yield.

Comment: getting error as: Specified cast is not valid. var parsedvalue = new DataTable(); int i = (int)parsedvalue.Compute(path, String.Empty); decimal d = (decimal)parsedvalue.Compute(path, String.Empty);

Comment: Like I said, the casting can be difficult because Compute elects the type based on the data. It will assuredly be either an integer, double, or decimal. You can use "is", or GetType() to determine the type dynamically. eg, object o = parsingEngine.Compute(myexprSTR, String,Empty); if(o is int) cast as int; else if(o is decimal) cast as decimal; else if (o is double) cast as double; etc.
It is also important to use expressions with proper supported symbols, ie '*' not 'x', '/' not '÷' etc. You cant use any string that COULD be math, you must use one that conforms to a subset of tradition.

Comment: if that still doesn't work, just print out GetType()'s return value, and it will apprise you of what Compute has encoded. Additionally, the two expressions in my answer, and their casts, are valid examples to help point you in the right direction.

Comment: The issue with the return of an `object` is easily taken care of by using `System.Convert`. So instead of casting you use `decimal d = System.Convert.ToDecimal(parseEngine.Compute(...));`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately .NET does not have anything built in that will evaluate a mathematical expression string. You'll need to use a third party library like [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/).

Then you can use it in your code like this

```
// original value
//string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"4'-8"x5/16"x20'-8 13/16"); This needs to be a filepath.
string text = @"4'-8x5/16x20'-8 13/16";

string path = text.Replace("'", "*12").Replace("-", "+").Replace("x", "+").Replace(" ", "+").Replace(@"""", "");
System.Console.WriteLine("The original string: '{0}'", text);
System.Console.WriteLine("The final string: '{0}'", path);

Expression e = new Expression(path)
Console.WriteLine(e.Evaluate);
```

Comment: Also `File.ReadAllText` needs a file path...it's taking the OPs math expression

Comment: I removed the portion throwing the expression. I left the incorrect `File.ReadAllText` from OP's answer since I'm assuming he or she put that in place to show us an example of expected text input. Even though it is formatted incorrectly....

Comment: .NET does have something that will evalueate a mathematical expression string, the DataTable. See my answer below.(about to write it)

Comment: @JoshuaHysong EDIT: Answer Written

Comment: @shulmaster that is very clever! Learned something new today =)